# RestAPI response is providing special characters within string

Tags: json, powershell, rest, byte-order-mark

I'm using below powershell script to call a RestAPI:

```
$Url = 'https://example.com'
$Body = @{
    "OperationType" = "new"
    "LongDescription" = "Test Description of Change"
    "ShortDescription" = "Test Short Description"
    "FuncUser" = "50"
    "ProductId" = "001575"
    "StepApproverPartnerid" = "58"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$headers = @{
    'ContentType' = 'application/json'
    'Accept' = 'application/json'
    'APIKey' = 'NUb9aDuEqb04Avg'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -contentType "application/json" -Uri $url -Method Post -body $Body -Headers $headers -OutFile rfc.json

Get-Content rfc.json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Xml -As Stream -Depth 3 | Out-File rfc.xml -Encoding utf8

get-content rfc.xml
```

Output of the rfc.xml is showing below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
<Property Name="LongDescription" Type="System.String">Testï¿½Descriptionï¿½ofï¿½Change</Property>
```

How can I skip these special characters like ï¿½ shown in the last line to appear in file.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-Content -Path rfc.json -Encoding utf8` ?

Comment: Thank you @Theo - It worked ! Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution.